# Is there any way to collect only variables with a specific power?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I've got this:

```
In[13]:= Expand[(a + b) (b + c) (c + a)]

Out[13]= a^2 b + a b^2 + a^2 c + 2 a b c + b^2 c + a c^2 + b c^2
```

And I want to collect only terms involving a^2.  In other words, I want the following output:

```
a^2(b + c) + a b^2 + 2 a b c + b^2 c + a c^2 + b c^2
```

How can I do this?  If I use the following:

```
Collect[%, a^2]
```

Then it simply groups terms into the highest power of a, even if the highest term is less than 2.  So it results in this:

```
In[14]:= Collect[%, a^2]

Out[14]= b^2 c + b c^2 + a^2 (b + c) + a (b^2 + 2 b c + c^2)
```

Ideally, I would like to extend this further to collect all a^2, b^2, and c^2 in one expression.  So that running my command would transform the original fully expanded expression into the following:

```
a^2(b + c) + b^2(a+c) + c^2(a+b) + 2 a b c
```

In a single command.  It this possible?

Comment: FYI (its not the answer to your question but...) another symmetric form would be given by `SymmetricReduction[Expand[(a + b) (b + c) (c + a)]
  , {a, b, c}][[1]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 4):

Introducing dummy variables will do the job:

```
Collect[Expand[(a + b) (b + c) (c + a)]
  /. {a^2 -> x, b^2 -> y, c^2 -> z}, {x, y, z}]/. {x -> a^2, y -> b^2, z -> c^2}
```

> 2 a b c + (a + b) c^2 + b^2 (a + c) + a^2 (b + c)

If you will have more variables in the future, it probably makes sense to rewrite this:

```
P = {a, b, c}; Q = {x, y, z};
Collect[Expand[(a + b) (b + c) (c + a)] 
   /. MapThread[#1^2 -> #2 &, {P, Q}], Q] /. MapThread[#2 -> #1^2 &, {P, Q}]
```

> 2 a b c + (a + b) c^2 + b^2 (a + c) + a^2 (b + c)

Answer (score 3):

How about `Coefficient`?

```
expr = Expand[(a + b) (b + c) (c + a)]
term = Coefficient[expr, a^2]*a^2 (* get the coefficient and multiply it with the variable *)
rest = (expr - term) // Expand (* expand the rest *)
term + rest
```

> ```
> a^2 b + a b^2 + a^2 c + 2 a b c + b^2 c + a c^2 + b c^2
>
> a^2 (b + c)
>
> a b^2 + 2 a b c + b^2 c + a c^2 + b c^2
>
> a b^2 + 2 a b c + b^2 c + a c^2 + b c^2 + a^2 (b + c)
> ```

The final line contains the `a^2(b + c)` term at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is quite different from the second one. To address the first one you might do as follows:

```
pos = Position[Collect[expr, a], a^2*b_][[1, 1]]
```

this yields 3. Then

```
Collect[expr, a][[pos]]
```

yielding a^2 (b + c)